# Comparison tool with option to check file names only?

Tags: comparison, diff

I'm looking for a folder comparison tool that has an option to check file names only, not timestamps or content.

I've tried Araxis Merge, Beyond Compare, and WinMerge, but none seem to have this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond Compare does support that.  Use the **Session->Session Settings...** menu item and on the **Comparison** tab uncheck everything.  If you want to check for case changes check the **Compare filename case** option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need a comparison list, that only schecks the name of the file, a very easy way to do it would be with two xcopy commands:

```
xcopy "<source>" "<dest>" /e /l /f >\fullList.txt

xcopy "<source>" "<dest>" /e /l /u /f >\equals.txt
```